# Eclipse auto refactor String comparision

Tags: java, eclipse, string, refactoring, conditional-statements

consider following code

1)    `if ("Anil".equals(name)) {`

is more preferrable than following (as it avoids NPEs)

2)    `if (name.equals("Anil")) {`

I am maintaining a class that is having full of 2nd type of conditions.
And i want to convert those conditions to type-1 (constant first).

So i am wondering if there is any shortcut in eclipse to do the same.
eclipse refactor menu is not showing any option that would do.

Answer (score 3):

Think you should probably use regexp to replace this:

```
(\w+).equals\(\"([\w]*)\"\)
```

with this:

```
\"$2\".equals($1)
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. I just want to point out that this won't switch around the `equals` call for values returned from a method (e.g. `myClass.getMyString().equals("Constant String")` won't get switched).

Answer (score 1):

I am developing the AutoRefactor Eclipse plugin that does what you want and a lot more.

You first need to install the plugin from the update site http://autorefactor.org/nightly.

Once this is done, you can simply press the combination Alt+Shift+Y and it will correctly revert all the calls to Object.equals() or String.equalsIgnoreCase() when the argument is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

No there isnt but you could try with an Eclipse macro recorder such as [Practically Macro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/files/)

Answer (score 0):

The best option I can think of is for you to write code to refactor code. Eclipse doesn't have a specific swap you are looking for.

Read the .java file like a regular file. Look for the above pattern, and try to replace it with the swap. That way you might practice some regex too.